# How to update my Django database with a submit button?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-database

I am creating a web application that will serve as a grocery store. The way I set it up is so the customer can come onto the website, click on the items that they would like to purchase, and then click a submit button to purchase those items. The problem I am running into is having a views.py function to take the information of which products were selected and subtracting 1 from the quantity of the database.

```
"""models.py"""
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    Sale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,default=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'

def inventory(request):
    products = request.POST.getlist('products')
    for product in products:
        a = Post.objects.get(title=product)
        a.quantity = a.quantity -1
        a.save()
    print(products) # This line isn't necessary but it will show what is in your list from the terminal.
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

urls.py

```
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('inventory', views.inventory, name='inventory'),
```

home.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'inventory' %}" method="POST" id="menuForm">
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2">{{ post.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" >{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
                <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.title }}" form="menuForm" name="products" > Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              </input>
              </div>
            </article>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" form="menuForm">Confirm Purchase</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

My goal is to click on the checkboxes, and when the customer clicks the button on the bottom of home.html, it triggers the inventory function to subtract "1" from the quantity. When I say print(products), then the terminal gives me the title of all the posts that are check-marked. However, it still isn't going into the database and subtracting 1 from the inventory. (I solved it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Post.objects.get('products[x]')` does not make sence, the [**`.get(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) expects `Q` objects as positional parameters, or *named* parameters, so for example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def inventory(request):
    products = request.POST.getlist('products')
    Post.objects.filter(pk__in=products).update(
        quantity=F('quantity')-1
    )
    return redirect('profile')
```

By using a [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) you decrement all `Post`s in *bulk* which is more efficient than making two database queries *per* Post object.

Using `HttpResponseRedirect("{% url 'profile'%}")` will not work either. The `"{% url 'profile'%}"` is just a string, it does not perform any template rendering. Django will normally return a *HTTP 302* response, with `{% url 'profile' %}` as link to go to, but the browser does not understand `{% url 'profile' %}`, it can only work with a URI.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response. I updated my code and this is the new error I now receive

Comment: @Yahya: you are again using a *string* instead of an `F` object...

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. However, I am not receiving any more errors. The problem is the code still does not do what I want it to do. I am trying to get all the checked boxes to have 1 get subtracted from the inventory when I press the "Confirm Purchase" button. But when I click the button, it just reloads the page and no changes are made to the database. Do you know if there is something wrong with the way I am calling the values of the checkboxes or is it something else. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Yahya: are you sure you make a POST request, and that the `request.POST.getlist('products')` contains a lists of primary keys?

Comment: When I did my research about capturing the values in checkboxes with Django, the majority of posts I saw said that this was an effective way to do it. I am a little new to Django, so I don't know much of the complex aspects of it.

Comment: @Yahya: but where is the `<form>` tag? You wrap the checkboxes in a form, and submit the form. It looks like you use an `<a href="">` which makes a GET request. Can you print the `print(products)` in your view, and look what the `products` contains?

Comment: When I say print(products), the terminal gives me "[]", which I assume is an empty list. So I'm guessing that the values are not being received properly.

Comment: @Yahya: are you sure you are making a POST request? You can normally see the request in the terminal. Anyway, you should definitely wrap the checkboxes in a `<form>` that makes a POST request to the view.

Comment: Hello, I finally figured out how to get the list to capture the values. Thank you for the tips on using form tags in the home.html. It is still not subtracting the database. But the terminal now shoes the title of every post that is checked. Thank you for the help you have given me.